# Magento-- add to cart-- url change

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

In My site when i click addtocart button it returns the following url:

http://mywebsite.com/ajax/index/add/uenc/a...cC5uZXQvYXBwbGlhbmNlcy5odG1s/product/83/isAjax/1

But i need the specific url which is below:

http://mywebsite.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/a...cC5uZXQvYXBwbGlhbmNlcy5odG1s/product/83/isAjax/1

can i know where to edit this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can change it in all your theme files.

However, if you want to change all add to cart behavior site wide you may want to extend the CartController and forward the add action to your own ajax module.

An example:

app/code/local/MyCompany/Ajax/controllers/CartController.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class MyCompany_Ajax_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController {

    public function addAction() {
        $this->_forward('add', 'index', 'ajax', $this->getRequest()->getParams());
    }

}
```

app/code/local/MyCompany/Ajax/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

    [...]

     <frontend>
           <routers>
                <checkout>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <mycompany_ajax before="Mage_Checkout">MyCompany_Ajax</mycompany_ajax>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
                </checkout>
            </routers>
        </frontend>
    </config>
```

Another way is to add an observer that listens to the controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add event and forward there.

Comment: i dont have the folder local in app/code/local....
i have installed a theme in magento

Comment: You can also change getAddUrl in Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart. If you are not familiar with module writing, there is too much for me to explain in this post. But you can just create the local dir. Magento will recognize it.

Comment: Sorry not at the moment. I can send you the files to put in app/code/local if you would like?

Comment: In the end there were files missing from app/code/local and a 500 server error on query attribute isAjax=1 had to be solved.